# Когда отключен denwer не работает Mysql

Tags: mysql, denwer

Я всегда без без проблем подключался к базам данных на своем компьютере по localhost через любые программы по типу navicat или просто через терминал в системе Windows 7. После того как я установил Denwer, если Denwer не включен, то и подключится к базам данных невозможно пока не включишь денвер. Раньше это не доставляло проблем Denwer всегда был включен, но мне понадобилось включить Open Server и поскольку он использует те же порты что и денвер, то вместе они работать не могут. И получается что через openserver я не могу работать с базами данных. Смотрел в службах там Mysql включен, его можно выключить, перезагрузить и включить. Но это ни на что не влияет. Пробовал различными командами из поиска запустить mysql все безрезультатно. Может кто-то сталкивался и может подсказать куда копать? Возможно если переустановить mysql все заработает, но я пока этого не хочу делать. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: C чего это нельзя работать в openserver  с БД? можно. просто они лежат в папке опенсервера, а у денвера в своей......просто перенести одни в другую и всё

Comment: Ну вот отключил я денвер. Через навикат больше доступа к базам нет, включаю openserver к чему мне подключаться через навикат? Или там как-то по другому работать  базой данных? Разве я не могу рутом подключится как хочу?

Comment: Разобрался... К старым базам я подключался не через рута, а через другого пользователя. И когда подключался при включенном opensever мне писало, что нет доступа, потом подключился через рута и все заработало в новой . Спасибо за внимание... Моя ошибка была в том что я думал, что denwer и openserver работают c одними и теми же базами данных в одной и той же системе MySQL, но это не так. Будьте внимательны к деталям...

Comment: `Моя ошибка была в том что я думал, что denwer и openserver работают c одними и теми же базами данных в одной и той же системе MySQL, но это не так.` - ага, я так и написал)) наверное недостаточно разборчиво))